# QGIS x ArcGIS - Geoprocessing Vectors in Geographic Coordinate Systems

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, vector, datum

Is there a possibility of in future versions of QGIS, the software be able to geoprocess vectors (clip, buffer, intersection, etc.) in Geographic Coordinate System, and not only in UTM?

In ArcGIS, the software calculates automatically the geographic vectors and do the maths behind the scenes and geoprocess your data, even if all of them are geographic.

Until today, the QGIS software is only capable to geoprocess vectors if all of them are UTM, and in the same datum.

Comment: Well, there's always a possibility. Plus it's open source so you could potentially fund/implement it yourself if it's important to you - that's how open source works.

Comment: I see no restriction in QGIS why all vectors have to be in UTM. You can do any processing in any CRS, as long as all layers are in the same CRS. Using the Processing models, it should be possible to do the reprojection in the background with temporary virtual layers.

Comment: You can choose to spend your money in "private licence" or in "open source developer works"...

Comment: Ok. I got it. I'm just curious about having this feature on QGIS too. Because I use it everyday at work and at home. Actually, I prefer to use QGIS than ArcGIS, and I try to do other people use more Open Source applications and leave the privates behind. I believe that's the future. =) Thank you guys for answering this question. I really wanna be a QGIS dev someday, and help the Open Source community. I'm still learning.